# rails - help trying to use models in sub-folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Rails 4 and ActiveAdmin with SQLite.

### 1. I've generated those models and moved files into folders:

```
app
  models
    system
       - admin_user.rb
       - customer.rb
    resources
       - document.rb
```

### 2. Added to config/application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '{**/}')]
```

### 3. In the model files I just added prefix to model name:

```
class System::AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable,
           :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable,
           :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

--

So, when I try to run `rake db:migrate` I get this error:

```
LoadError: Unable to autoload constant AdminUser, expected /Users/john/testing/app/models/System/admin_user.rb to define it
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: try the alternate way like module System, class AdminUser, end, end.

Comment: can you post an example?

Comment: module System
  class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end

Comment: Remove the `System::` and use `class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rails is automagically able to find correctly-namespaced classes in subfolders of app/models without your having to do anything special.  Since you've added subfolders of app/models to the autoload path, Rails now expects to find non-namespaced classes in those locations.

If you delete the autoload path change and define your class as Mohanraj suggested:

```
# app/models/system/admin_user.rb
module System
  class AdminUser
    # your code here
    # ...
  end
end
```

then you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: I made this your way and re-generated ActiveAdmin file with `rails g active_admin:resource System::AdminUser` and now it works. Thanks!